# Adding an ontextchanged event to a textbox within the signup component

Tags: asp.net, .net, registration

i am trying to add a username availability checker to the signup component and i used this :

```
    protected void checkUser(object sender, EventArgs e)//checking the user name avaliabilty
{ 
    if (Membership.GetUser(UsernameCheck.Text) != null)
    {
        usernameResult.Text = "User Name already Taken";
    }
    else 
    {
        usernameResult.Text = "User Name Avaliable";
    }
}
```

and this is my aspx :

```
  <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
                                CssClass="SuserNameBox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="checkUser" >Name Extension</asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." 
                                ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="mainSignUp">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
```

but the ontextchanged event wont trigger (i tried it with an external text box and it worked fine) .

so my question is how to trigger an event to an element within the sign up component

using asp.net 3.5

thanks

Comment: Not sure if that's the problem, but you would really want to do this within an update panel to get ajax support

Comment: Did you try putting it in an update panel with a trigger?

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin - i have tried it within an update panel but still didn't work

Comment: @Chad - could you explain more please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px"
                 CssClass="SuserNameBox" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="checkUser" >Name Extension</asp:TextBox>   
                 <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UserName" EventName="TextChanged" />
                 </Triggers>                         
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Something like this.

Comment: i tried it and it gave me this error `Could not find an event named 'OnTextChanged' on associated control 'UserName' for the trigger in UpdatePanel `

Comment: Sorry event is just TextChanged